# What happened to the ServiceStackHttpHandlerFactory in Service Stack v4?

Tags: .net, servicestack, nuget

I'm following a tutorial on building a site with ASP.NET MVC and Service Stack.

When I pull the latest version of Service Stack, I get:

"Could not load type 'ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.SeviceStackHttpHandlerFactory' from assembly 'ServiceStack'."

and SerivceStack.WebHost.Endpoints doesn't appear in the object browser.

If I specifically install a version less than 4, it works and it's in the object browser.

I can't seem to find any information on where those files went, and what to do instead.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A lot of classes were moved around, with an aim to simplify the namespaces. That class is now `ServiceStack.HttpHandlerFactory` in the main `ServiceStack` assembly.

When upgrading from ServiceStack 3 to 4, you will need to update the handlers entries in web.config. Here's the new canonical config:

```
<add path="*" name="ServiceStack.Factory" type="ServiceStack.HttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" resourceType="Unspecified" allowPathInfo="true" />
```